# Disable qt creator auto build when debug

Tags: debugging, qt, qt-creator

How to disable qt creator from auto building when trying to debug?

Currently when debug button is clicked, it automatically starts build. I want to disable this and just proceed to debug.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Navigate to Tools/Options.
Select Projects, General tab.
Uncheck "Always build project before running".

Comment: The menu item was probably removed or renamed. Please update the answer for QtCreator 3.5.1 and above.

Comment: It's in the Build & Run section of Options now.

Comment: Looks like the option is now "Always deploy project before running it" (or "Always build project before deploying it").

Comment: I have QT Creator 3.6.0, ,the option for me was Tools>Options, select Build & Run in the left column, select the General tab, uncheck "Always build project before deploying it". The reason I want to do this is in my .pro file I have a setup that generates header files containing versioning information (queried from git) before the build actually starts. When the build finishes it erases these files (so they don't get stale). Since the project depends on these headers, it would see they were missing, then rebuild everything when I tried to debug. No thanks, easier to manage building manually.

Answer (score -3):

That is not probably what you really want, since your source code may become out of sync with the binary. That is why this is enforced.

Comment: I would like to disable auto build. I've a huge source code (webkit engine) and I would like to debug again and again keeping breakpoints at different places. The time taken to start the build itself will be around 1 minute and I would not like it to build every time in spite of me not modifying the code.

Comment: If you don't modify th build, nothing should be rebuilt?

Comment: @Frank,
That should be the case, but it doesn't always work that way.  I don't know if this is the asker's issue, but my company's makefiles used to always rebuild the code, which was quite annoying.  Just recently did we have a makefile master change the makefiles so that they did not rebuild every time.  With our particular issue, we had some dummy targets that copied files around, forcing a rebuild every time.

Comment: @Frank: Yes.. Nothing won't be built. But make will start probing whether to build or not. And that takes considerable amount of time.

Comment: People who enforce such things are just too dumb to figure out all the consequences. Such as when I kill the program just to start it again.